# Code splitting with webpack and vuejs not pointing to the correct output folder

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, code-splitting

I have a route provider with the following imports:

```
const Landing = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Landing" */ "../pages/landing/Landing.vue");
const FramesPage = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "FramesPage" */ "@/pages/frames/FramesPage.vue");
const SingleChartPage = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "SingleChartPage" */ "@/pages/singleChart/SingleChartPage.vue");
```

And the following webpack.config.js

`output: {
    path: path.resolve("../public"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js"
}`

When the `App.vue` loads the `<router-view></router-view>` component, it throws a 404.

The files are being split correctly and put in my `/public` folder but the initial GET from vue is no longer pointing to that public folder and goes straight to my root app:

> GET http://localhost/MyApp/Landing.bundle.js

instead of `http://localhost/MyApp/public/Landing.bundle.js`

[image: devtools_code_splitting_error]

Any ideas?

EDIT:

If I add a `publicPath` to the output, all it does is export the js files to `public/public/chuckfile.js` but it also tries to reference all my other assets to `public/public`

Comment: `If I add a publicPath to the output, all it does is export the js files to public/public/chuckfile.js`: setting the `publicPath` shouldn't change where the files are outputted, only the URLs that reference them.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the behaviour I've had. The only way I've kinda fixed it is by setting `__webpack_public_path__ = "public/";` in my app.js.

Comment: Actually my apologies you are correct. It was appending the `public/` to the path only. I had `filename: "public/[name].bundle.js"` that was causing the issue. The reason I couldn't use publicPath is because it was also updating the path of all my other assets which I didn't want.